# How to replace String with an image using JS

Tags: javascript, replace, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a chat system which consist of Smilies :) . i'm using react js and i want to check and replace the smiley symbols in the receiving string.

```
  return(<ListItem
           leftAvatar={<Avatar src="profile pic" />}
           primaryText="Name"
           secondaryText={
          <p>
         {item.message}
         </p>
          }
           secondaryTextLines={2}
          />
               );
```

the string i want to check is given by {item.message}. ive tried to replace the string with `{item.message}.replace(/:)/g,'<img src="../../../img/smileys/smile53893.gif"/>');`

but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing there is that you are inserting the image tag as an string into the DOM. You need to create real react elements, and replace the `:)` with the `<img/>` elements.

Here is a simplified version your code. Made also a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e4ed7pfs/3/) about this for you.

```
var texts = item.message.split(/:\)/g);
var content = [];
for(var i = 0; i < texts.length - 1; i++) {
  content.push(texts[i]);
  content.push(<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Bye.gif'/>);
}
return <div>{content}</div>;
```

Comment: thanks its working but i've a small issue when ever i pass a string without a smiley it doesn't return anything. and even if i pass a string containing a smiley the text after the smiley will not be displayed. please help.

Comment: @TRomesh did you ever figure out how to have it display the text without an emoji? Currently debugging the same issue. Thanks!